# Solve Liouville equation for Liouville operator numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, statistical-mechanics

For a deterministic dynamical system $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = F(\mathbf{x})$ with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the [Liouville equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) governs the evolution of probability densities $\rho(\mathbf{x}, t)$:

$$
\frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{x}, t)}{\partial t} = -\nabla \mathbf{\cdot}[F(\mathbf{x}) \rho(\mathbf{x}, t)] = \hat{L}\rho(\mathbf{x}, t)
$$

where $\hat{L}$ is the Liouville operator. For an initial distribution $\rho_0 = \rho(\mathbf{x}, t=0)$ this equation has the solution

$$
\rho_t = \mathrm{exp} \left(t \hat{L} \right) \rho_0.
$$

For a given vector field $F$ and initial distribution $\rho_0$ the first equation can be solved numerically for $\rho_t$ for example with finite difference methods - however I would like to solve for the operator $\hat{L}$ (approximated as a matrix). How can I go about doing this?

Best regards!

Comment: Assuming you know how to approximate your operator with a matrix, all you need is to compute the matrix exponential. You may use [EXPOKIT](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/), for example.

Comment: @uranix I don't have an approximation for $\hat{L}$ yet, that is what I am after

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is found in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4166): first estimate the [Perron-Frobenius operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_operator) for small $t$, and then differentiate numerically (Equation 13).